# how to declare a variable in pl sql the right way?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

here is my code

```
  vJS     VARCHAR2(3500); --25065
     gMaxDays    s_criteria%rowtype := get_criteria_rec('MAX_DAYS_BOOKING');

BEGIN
  IF NOT Sec_Pkg.chk_sec('ATLAS_INV_OVERBOOK') THEN
       -- Exit procedure if security did not pass
       RETURN;
   END IF;
    --
    vJS :=  ' gMaxDays;'||CHR(10)||
            'function checkfields() {' ||CHR(13) ||
            '    // Setting the target here' ||CHR(13) ||
            '    document.frmInvSelect.target="_top"' ||CHR(13) ||
```

i created gMaxDays,at first i had it hardcoded but now its on a table called s_criteria and  MAX_DAYS_BOOKING is part of s_criteria. im i calling it the right way?

this is how it use to look and it work

```
  vJS     VARCHAR2(3500); --25065

BEGIN
  IF NOT Sec_Pkg.chk_sec('ATLAS_INV_OVERBOOK') THEN
       -- Exit procedure if security did not pass
       RETURN;
   END IF;
    --
    vJS :=  'var gMaxDays = 366;'||CHR(10)||
            'function checkfields() {' ||CHR(13) ||
            '    // Setting the target here' ||CHR(13) ||
            '    document.frmInvSelect.target="_top"' ||CHR(13) ||
        [/code]
```

Comment: Do you have any error ? If so, which one ?

Comment: i actually dont get a error, it just doesnt do any search

Comment: What do you mean ? Is your variable empty ?

Comment: NO is not empty the module max_days_booking inlcludes a row=366

Comment: the row in include_list

Answer (score 0):

Err ... Are you saying that

You used to have a code snippet that "worked":

```
vJS :=  'var gMaxDays = 366;'||CHR(10)||
        'function checkfields() {' ||CHR(13) ||
        '    // Setting the target here' ||CHR(13) ||
        '    document.frmInvSelect.target="_top"' ||CHR(13) ||
```

When you modified the snippet to be:

```
vJS :=  ' gMaxDays;'||CHR(10)||
        'function checkfields() {' ||CHR(13) ||
        '    // Setting the target here' ||CHR(13) ||
        '    document.frmInvSelect.target="_top"' ||CHR(13) ||
```

It "works" no more ?

I guess you're trying to generate a JavaScript code snippet. Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
declare
  vJS VARCHAR2(3500);
  gMaxDays s_criteria%rowtype := get_criteria_rec('MAX_DAYS_BOOKING');
begin
  -- here you have to call the correct field from the record
  -- in this example I assume it's max_day
  vJS := 'var gMaxDays = ' || gMaxDays.max_day || ';' || CHR(10)||
         'function checkfields() {' || CHR(10) ||
         '    // Setting the target here' || CHR(10) ||
         '    document.frmInvSelect.target="_top"' || CHR(10) ||
         ' // Add here something that makes this a valid JavaScript.'
end;
```

Check what the documentation says about PL/SQL [record variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/composites.htm#CIHFCFCJ).

Comment: where are you getting max_day from?

Comment: when i put it var gmaxdays it can search all the database, but i only want it to be able to search for 366 days whick is what i put in the table

Comment: @user1289509 Because you don't tell all necessary details (the structure of `s_criteria%rowtype`) I have to make assuptions. In my example I assume the relevant field of `gMaxDays` record is `max_days`. In your real code you check the record and use the correct field. If this makes no sense for you I recommend you study PL/SQL documentation about records.